# How do I get an img to display after clicking a submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this loader-bar gif that is by default invisible:

```
     <p class="loadingImg" style="display:none;"><img src="/design/styles/_shared/classic-loader.gif" alt="" /></p>
```

When the user hits the submit button at the bottom of the form, I want that gif to be displayed, and for the submit button to disappear. Basically the submit button should be replaced by this loader bar so that the user knows to wait before clicking again. I believe I can use some onclick javascript... 
Help?

Comment: is your submit button using AJAX, or is it submitting your form?

Comment: @Elangovan it's just submitting the form. Nothing fancy. Plain ol' html is my forte`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way with jQuery:

Add jquery to your site

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add the code below inside `<script>` tags or an external js file.
The text between the quotes is the selector for your submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-btn-id').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.loadingImg').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between .loadingImg and p.loadingImg as in @Andre's response? Also, #submit should be #theIDofthesubmitbutton, right?

Comment: You can use either p.loadingImg or .loadingImg - they target the same element. If "theIDofthesubmitbutton" is the ID of your submit button then yep use that.

Comment: Woohoo, I finally got it to work! Please disregard all my noob comments... :D thanks @marissa.c and everyone

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
        $('p.loadingImg').show();
    });
});
```

1- You can also disable the submit button to avoid a second click, using $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); in the click event

2- if your form is submited by ajax, it's better for you to treat this in the ajax call

Comment: Pardon my total jquery-ignorance, but how do I call a jquery function from my submit button? Do I just use an onclick="" event?

Comment: @robhardgood, @Andre's JS code should just go in a `<script>` block. The code takes care of finding the submit button (line 2), and adding an `onclick` function to it. It's totally separate from your HTML and should stay that way

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery submit event handler.

```
$("#form1").submit(function() 
              {
                 $('#submit1').hide();
                 $('.loadingImg').show();
                 return true;
              });
```

Check this link for API reference http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: This will hide the whole form on submit. OP requested that only the submit button should disappear

Comment: @marissa, Updated my script to include button id instead of 'this'

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing this without jQuery:

```
<form id="f">
  <input />
  <p id="p" style="display:none;">Loading!</p>
  <input id="b" type="submit" />  
</form>   
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (d) {
  d.getElementById('f').onsubmit = function () { 
    d.getElementById('b').style.display = 'none';
    d.getElementById('p').style.display = 'block'; 
  };
}(document));  
</script>
```